# Weave Inline C++ Code in Python 2.7

Tags: python, c++, python-2.7, scipy

I'm trying to rewrite this function:

```
def smoothen_fast(heightProfile, travelTime):

    smoothingInterval = 30 * travelTime

    heightProfile.extend([heightProfile[-1]]*smoothingInterval)
    # Get the mean of first `smoothingInterval` items
    first_mean = sum(heightProfile[:smoothingInterval]) / smoothingInterval
    newHeightProfile = [first_mean]

    for i in xrange(len(heightProfile)-smoothingInterval-1):
        prev = heightProfile[i]  # the item to be subtracted from the sum
        new = heightProfile[i+smoothingInterval] # item to be added
        # Calculate the sum of previous items by multiplying
        # last mean with smoothingInterval
        prev_sum = newHeightProfile[-1] * smoothingInterval
        new_sum = prev_sum - prev + new
        mean = new_sum / smoothingInterval
        newHeightProfile.append(mean)

    return newHeightProfile
```

as embedded C++ Code:

```
import scipy.weave as weave
heightProfile = [0.14,0.148,1.423,4.5]
heightProfileSize = len(heightProfile)
travelTime = 3

code = r"""
    #include <string.h>
    int smoothingInterval = 30 * travelTime;
    double *heightProfileR = new double[heightProfileSize+smoothingInterval];
    for (int i = 0; i < heightProfileSize; i++)
    {
        heightProfileR[i] = heightProfile[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < smoothingInterval; i++)
    {
        heightProfileR[heightProfileSize+i] = -1;
    }
    double mean = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < smoothingInterval; i++)
    {
        mean += heightProfileR[i];
    }
    mean = mean/smoothingInterval;
    double *heightProfileNew = new double[heightProfileSize-smoothingInterval];
    for (int i = 0; i < heightProfileSize-smoothingInterval-1; i++)
    {
        double prev = heightProfileR[i];
        double newp = heightProfile[i+smoothingInterval];
        double prev_sum = heightProfileNew[i] * smoothingInterval;
        double new_sum = prev_sum - prev + newp;
        double meanp = new_sum / smoothingInterval;
        heightProfileNew[i+1] = meanp;
    }
    return_val = Py::new_reference_to(Py::Double(heightProfileNew));
"""
d = weave.inline(code,['heightProfile','heightProfileSize','travelTime'])
```

As a return type i need the `heightProfileNew`. I need the access it like a list in Python later.

I look at these examples:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/weave.html

He keeps telling me that he doesn't know `Py::`, but in the examples there are no Py-Includes?

Comment: Your title says C, your question says C++/C and is tagged C++, not C, and your code is a mix of C++ and C. Choose *one* of those languages!

Answer (score 1):

I know, the question is old, but I think it is still interesting.

Assuming your using weave to improve computation speed and that you know the length of your output beforehand, I suggest that you create the result before calling `inline`. That way you can create the result variable in python (very easy). I would also suggest using a `nd.ndarray` as a result because it makes shure you use the right datatype. You can iterate `ndarrays` in python the same way you iterate lists.

```
import numpy as np
heightProfileArray = np.array(heightprofile) 
# heightProfileArray = np.array(heightprofile, dtype = np.float32) if you want to make shure you have the right datatype. Another choice would be np.float64
resultArray = np.zeros_like(heightProfileArray) # same array size and data type but filled with zeros
[..]
weave.inline(code,['heightProfile','heightProfileSize','travelTime','resultArray'])
for element in resultArray:
    print element
```

In your C++-code you can then just assign values to elements of that array:

```
[..]
resultArray[i+1] = 5.5;
[..]
```